# WSO2 EMM stops working when user update iOS version

Tags: wso2, mdm, wso2-iot

WSO2 EMM version: 2.0.1

Database: MySQL

Scenario: BYOD (Non-supervised)

WSO2 EMM is not working after use upgrade iOS version. This happens when I upgrade the iOS version from iOS 9.2 to 9.3.

> Exception on Server: "Data too long for column UNLOCK_TOKEN" 
>   Class:org.wso2.carbon.device.mgt.mobile.impl.ios.dao.impl.IOSDeviceDAOImpl

I accidently deleted server log. I can't downgrade my iOS device & then try again.

Please help me. It's not WSO2's open-source class, so I can't compile & reuse it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that the EMM version 2.0.1 has not been tested on iOS 9.3.x (1) since the product relases was done prior to the iOS release 9.3.x release.

However the issue seems to be caused by column length of the column UNLOCK_TOKEN, that is too small to hold the token sent by iOS 9.3.x devices. As a solution, you can increase the column length of UNLOCK_TOKEN column in IOS_DEVICE table of the iOS related database.

(1). https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM201/Prerequisites

Comment: Please make iOS code also open-source. The open-source community will greatly help to improve the product.

Comment: This is not possible because it is Apple's proprietary code/protocol and we are not permitted to make it publicly available as per the licence grant we receive from Apple. Did my first answer answered your original question? If so please mark it as accepted.

Comment: Thanks. I really appreciate your help. Is there any way we can be your development partner to speed up the process of bug fixes & develop a better product?